# python closing db in cog file says its still running, error

Tags: python, sqlite, discord

Our discord bot uses sqlit3 to retrieve data, but sometimes due to traffic or error get db locked.
Inorder to fix this we have to copy and paste so i made a function to copy paste adn delete all old file
.BUt even after closing connection its says the db is still opened,

```
def db_lock():
        
        discord.close()
        base_directory = os.getcwd().replace(os.sep , '/')
        original = base_directory+'/discord.db'
        new_file = base_directory+'/discord_locked.db'
        os.rename(original, new_file)
        shutil.copyfile(new_file, orginal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely there is some program that is still using the database and keeping it open. On windows you can try with this software to check wich one is and close it:
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html

Otherwise in Linux (or also MacOS) you can try something similar using *fuser*:

```
 $ fuser discord.db
```

The output of the previously command should be the **PID of the process** that is using your db keeping it open.
So now you just need to kill you process executing the following command:

```
kill -9 PID
```

Where *PID* is the one that fuser returned before.

Comment: when i try to change name myself, it says opened in python, is it because its in cog folder. i open the db in cog folder, so still maybe running in main file??? cuz if i close the py files i can change name

Comment: i was just stupid the db was opened in the program by another cog forgot about it :?